# Need an CassandraBolt class description

Tags: java, cassandra, bigdata, apache-storm

Below is the source code of cassadraBolt class which receive the tuple(word,count) from Testwordcounter bolt class. I want to know what is actually happening with that tuple in the source code. And also need the explanation of writetuple() function, prepare() function, tuplemapper,incrementcounter() function. please give me the solution. This question may be silly but i need that. so thanks in advance.
//Source Code

```
private String clientConfigKey;

protected AstyanaxClient<K, C, V> client;

protected TupleMapper<K, C, V> tupleMapper;
protected Map<String, Object> stormConfig;

public CassandraBolt(String clientConfigKey, TupleMapper<K, C, V> tupleMapper) 
{
this.tupleMapper = tupleMapper;
// this.columnNameClass = columnNameClass;
// this.columnValueClass = columnValueClass;
this.clientConfigKey = clientConfigKey;

    LOG.debug("Creating Cassandra Bolt (" + this + ")");
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void prepare(Map<String, Object> stormConf, TopologyContext context) {
    Map<String, Object> config = (Map<String, Object>) stormConf.get(this.clientConfigKey);
    this.client = new AstTupleMapperyanaxClient<K, C, V>();
    this.client.start(config);
}

public void cleanup() {
    this.client.stop();
}

public void writeTuple(Tuple input, TupleMapper<K, C, V> tupleMapper) throws Exception {
    this.client.writeTuple(input, tupleMapper);
}

public void writeTuples(List<Tuple> inputs, TupleMapper<K, C, V> tupleMapper) throws Exception {
    this.client.writeTuples(inputs, tupleMapper);
}

public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
    return null;
}

public void incrementCounter(Tuple input, TupleCounterMapper tupleMapper) throws Exception {
    this.client.incrementCountColumn(input, tupleMapper);
}

public void incrementCounters(List<Tuple> inputs, TupleCounterMapper tupleMapper) throws Exception {
    this.client.incrementCountColumns(inputs, tupleMapper);
}
```